# Sujud as sahu for repeating fatiha in order to correct

Tags: mistake, sujud, surat-al-fatihah

Do we need to do sujud as sahu for repeating fatiha in salah in order to correct a word or ayah before going to sujud

Answer (score 0):

Sūratul Fātiha is one of the compulsory parts of Salat, according to the 4 schools of Fiqh except The Hanafīs. The Compulsory part cannot be corrected with Sujud-Sahwi, if intentionally omitted or ignored.
In this case, Sūratul Fātiha can not be corrected with Sujud-Sahwi but can be repeated to corrected mistakes without making any Sujud at the end of the Salat.
The Salat is valid without making any Sujud.